# contextMenu not working in Chrome Packaged App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Packaged App and I can't seem to figure out how to add contextMenus to it.

This is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Dialer",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "audioCapture"
  ],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128":"icon_128.png"
  }
}
```

and this is my background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create ({
        title: "%s", 
        contexts: ["all"],
        id: "right-click"
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? The menu item doesn't appear when I right click.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error getting returned (check chrome.runtime.lastError using a callback)? And what does setting the id have to do with handling right clicks?

Comment: Strange thing is that I don't get any errors in the console. The id is just something I put in. When I run the code in the console I get "undefined" back.

Comment: From the docs: "Note that if an error occurs during creation, you may not find out until the creation callback fires". The creation callback is an optional second argument to chrome.contextMenus.create: `chrome.contextMenus.create({...}, function() { console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError); });

Comment: @MatrixFrog thanks for the explanation. I added the code to chrome.runtime.lastError and I get undefined in the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the Chrome App Sample at 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/context-menu to get a sense of how it works.

As you can see, the context menu will appear in your Chrome App Window:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {bounds:{ width: 300, height: 300}});
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // When the app gets installed, set up the context menus
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Click on me',
    id: 'contextMenuId',
    contexts: [ 'all' ]
  });
});
```

If you're looking for context menus inside Chrome Browser though, you might want to create a Chrome Extension. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html